# What kind of converter do I need?

Tags: power

My girlfriend bought an electric grill from Thailand.

- Voltage/Frequency - 220v/50Hz
- Power - 1,300W
- Current - 6A

I have what I think is a just an adapter (it has all the different plug types) 100-240V - 2.5A max.

So I don't think it can be used. I think I need a step up converter.

[Is this what I would need?](https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B07C582G9P/ref=sspa_dk_detail_0?psc=1&pd_rd_i=B07C582G9P&pf_rd_m=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB&pf_rd_p=6140433799183340973&pf_rd_r=0J14X71CH7HGX4YBTFYQ&pd_rd_wg=vUNRZ&pf_rd_s=desktop-dp-sims&pf_rd_t=40701&pd_rd_w=FcBhm&pf_rd_i=desktop-dp-sims&pd_rd_r=51789015-558f-11e8-8ad2-a13608e9d62f)

Comment: No. That one is step-down, you need exactly opposite of that. You need a one that converts 110 from mains to 220 for this device.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about traveling.

Comment: Asking about a converter it's always a good idea to say in which country you're going to use the device.

Comment: Although I see converters rated for 3000W and 5000W on Amazon, I'd still be skeptical. The 3000W says not to use heat-creating appliances. The 5000W costs over $100—how much was the grill?!

Comment: It was about $30CDN, so don't want to spend a ton on the converter.

Comment: Start over and buy a new grill.  I am pretty sure you will not find a 1300W 110->220 converter for anywhere near $30 CDN (especially if it also needs to convert the frequency).  Keep in mind that 1300W at 110V is 12 amps, and that's also getting close to the maximum current of your circuit breaker.

Comment: What country are you wanting to use this grill in?

Comment: @NateEldredge - Yea, I had my doubts when buying it, my gf thought she had a converter but neither of us did the research what we really needed(kinda hard to do it while on vacation), decided to take the risk as it was not terribly expensive and it a grill that is going to be hard to find in Canada.